# .NET Core 3.1 framework provided DI - how to get the instance of already registered type?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-3.1, servicecollection

In my .NET Core 3.1 `Startup.cs`, I'm trying to get the instance of an already registered type i.e. `IBusinessLogic` using `IServiceCollection`, but it is not working.

How to get the instance of already registered type in .NET Core 3.1?

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {    
        container.Register<IBusinessLogic, BusinessLogic>();

        container.AddSingleton<Func<string, string>>
            ((username, password) => new JWTCache(userId, password, 
            container.GetInstance<IBusinessLogic>())); //container.GetInstance<IBusinessLogic>() not working
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [overload that gives you an `IServiceProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions_AddSingleton__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Func_System_IServiceProvider___0__):

```
container.AddSingleton<Func<string, string>>(
    sp => (username, password) => new JWTCache(userId, password, sp.GetRequiredService<IBusinessLogic>())
);
```